# how to support "require group foobar" in mod_auth_cas

Tags: apache, cas

I am using mod_auth_cas to protect my tsdb site, and the example as follows. when I use "require valid-user", it works well. but I want to only allow some people view my site, so I use "require group foobar" in the apache conf, but I don't know how to make it works. I have tried add extra "groups" attributes on my rubycas-server, but it not works.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
CASLoginURL https://cas.example.com/login
CASValidateURL https://cas.example.com/serviceValidate
CASValidateServer Off
CASDebug On

ServerName tsdb.example.com
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4242/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4242/
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Location />
AuthType CAS
require group foobar
# require valid-user
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The latest development version of mod_auth_cas now supports

```
Require cas-attribute <attribute>~<value>
```

which can be used to test group membership (source [1]).  The format of this attribute and regular expression may vary depending on your CAS server.  If your groups are in LDAP, you can also combine mod_auth_cas with mod_authnz_ldap, with CAS providing authentication, and LDAP providing authorization, for example:

```
AuthType CAS
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.example.com/ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)" STARTTLS
AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
Require ldap-group cn=my_role,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

If you want to use "Require ldap-group", which will authorize via mod_authnz_ldap, in conjunction with "Require user", which will authorize using mod_auth_cas, then make sure to include "AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off" (CASAuthoritative already defaults to off).

[1] https://github.com/Jasig/mod_auth_cas (note that version 1.0.10 has not actually been released yet)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CAS deals with groups at all.  It only handles authentication, so it can only tell you that you're logged in - but it does not do authorization.